# Use of "except on that day"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I would like to ask about "except on that day".

- "I want to take a lesson and managing my schedules. On next Tuesday I can't take lesson but others are fine for me."

In this situation, can I use the following sentence?

- "I can't take a lesson on the next Tuesday, I would like to take lessons except on that day."

Answer (score 1):

- Since you are already talking about a specific Tuesday, the article is unnecessary ➞ "*I can't take a lesson next Tuesday*."
- "*Would like to*" says more about your willingness than about practicality: "*I would like to have lessons every day, but my schedule is full this week*" would be a perfectly acceptable phrase, meaning you can't actually be present during any of the lessons.
  Similarly, if you simply are unable to take a lesson on said Tuesday, you could phrase it like this:

  > "*I would like to take lessons every day, but I can't next Tuesday.*"

  This still sounds a bit strange, because technically it means "*I can't like it next Tuesday*". I think most people would understand this, however, and I mostly wanted to add it for comparison.

  Other options:

  > "*I can take lessons every (single) day, except on Tuesday.*"

  > "*I have a full schedule next Tuesday. I can attend lessons every day this week except on that day.*"
- If you want to stay close to your original phrasing, and just have it corrected with the above pointers in mind:

  > "*I can't take a lesson next Tuesday. I can take lessons every day except on that day.*"

---

User *Old Brixtonian* raises an interesting point in [their answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/317194/86155) about 'taking lessons', but that's based on the assumption you used the 'wrong' verb, which you might not have (which could also mean I used the wrong interpretation above).

However, while I'm not British, I doubt this is typical for British English in general: based on my experience (and online searches to check up on this), 'to take lessons' seems to be a perfectly fine way to say you are 'on the receiving end of a lesson'.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation !
I will use normal phrases.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK it's usually the *teacher* who 'takes' the lesson. In the US it *may* be the student.

In the UK we might say,

> I'm afraid I can't get to next Tuesday's lesson. Any other day
> would be fine. Could we reschedule it?

Comment: ohh That is nice information.    I need to get more lesson !